# Combined width of child elements of an ul equals more than their sum

Tags: html, css, menu, header, navigation

**Answered**

I begin to think I am losing my mind...
Currently I'm trying to set up a simple top navigation which is margin-0-auto-ed in the header. It contains five children `<li>`-elements with each a width of 200px. If I can still calculate correctly, that equals 1000px in width. 
But to hold all children the top `<ul>`-element requires 1016px width. I just don't get where this comes from. All margins, paddings etc. are removed by a CSS Reset.
Code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
                <ul id="head-menu">
                    <li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a></li>
                    <li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a></li>
                    <li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a></li>
                    <li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a></li>
                    <li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-wrapper         { width: 100%; height: 56px; position: relative }
#header                 { width: 100%; height: 56px; background: #111; position: absolute; }
#head-menu              { width: calc(5*200px); margin: 0 auto;}
.head-menu-item         { display: inline-block }
.head-menu-item-link    { display: inline-block; padding: 20px; width: calc(200px - 40px); text-align: center }
```

**Update 29.09.13**

If anyone wonders, instead of commenting out the white spaces or going for some negative left-margins, I just used this syntax:

```
</li><li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a>
</li><li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a>
```

That has done it easily, without altering the code too much and keeps it clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `inline elements` add a extra space between each other because of the empty space on your html ( even a simple line-break ) here is your fix [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNvU4/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <ul id="head-menu">
            <li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a>
            </li><!--
            --><li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a>
            </li><!--
            --><li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a>
            </li><!--
            --><li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a>
            </li><!--
            --><li class="head-menu-item"><a href="" class="head-menu-item-link">Navlink</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> </div>
```

Comment: Do you think there would be any problem with using `display:table-cell` vs `display:inline-block`?  I know there are some browser compatibility issues with `display:table-cell`.

Comment: The only problem using table-cell instead of inline-block, in my opnion is the browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-block` is inserting spaces in between the li's (that is, displaying the white space shown in the HTML).  You can see this more clearly if you put a background color on the li's.

Comment: But how can I show the elements as a horizontal list without using `display:inline-block`? Or is there a way to remove this spacing? I somehow never encountered this problem before...

Comment: Look my answer @MoritzFriedrich

Comment: You can edit your HTML to remove the spaces between the li's, for one possibility.  There are also CSS options if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: One cool CSS option is to set the font-size of the UL to 0, and then set the font size of the LIs back to the normal size.

Comment: The best way is comment the empty space, is clean and don't need extra CSS

Comment: Okay that is a really wicked thing... Well thank all you guys and have a nice day! :-)

Answer (score 0):

or else if you just want your html to look neat, you can add a negative margin to the display:inline-block elements (to account for the gaps between them in html code), but it would work only if you have a kinda fixed layout, which rarely changes, and you are too adamant to mess up your code by removing spaces or adding comments

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough 'reputation' to comment, but I would like to restate something Vinícius Moraes said, WHITE SPACES in you code ie...

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="thing"></div>
```

as seen here by putting on different lines (creating a coded white space) can make a a dramatic effect, where putting...

```
<div id="foo"></div><div id="bar"></div><div id="thing"></div>
```

can create the desired effect, as I found after spending several hours wondering why my three 's where next lining when positioned perfectly with a jquery resize. Thank you again Vinícius Moraes for pointing out this rookie mistake.